# XText2 adoption and migration

Tags: eclipse, migration, dsl, xtext

Does anyone here try to adopt xtext2 and migrate from xtext1.x to xtext2.0?
It seems xtext2 brings many new atractive features. Such as A Reusable Expression Language and Xtend: A Code Generation Language . Many performance enhancement is made to the Xtext workbench and rename capability. So any one tell you experence about xtext2? Probably this is a bit early question. But I just wait and see.

[xtext2 homepage](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/downloads/?project=xtext)

Answer (score 2):

I updated an existing, not too complex language from Xtext 1 to Xtext 2, and tried to develop a new one using Xtext2 and XBase. I had to re-run the code generation step, and also had to modify the hand-written validators, because the error and warnings locations are to be specified using literals instead of integers. E.g.

`error("File does not exist with path: " + path, fileReference, ViatraTestDslPackage.FILE__PATH);`

is to be replaced with

`error("File does not exist with path: " + path, ViatraTestDslPackage.Literals.FILE__PATH);`

Similarly, the workflow has to be changed as well to incorporate some new features: the outline API uses different fragments (outline.OutlineTreeProviderFragment and outline.QuickOutlineFragment), for rename and compare support new fragments are to be added (refactoring.RefactorElementNameFragment and compare.CompareFragment).

With my experiments of XBase it seems, that adding that to a language that already supported some kind of expressions can be labour-intensive, because either old expressions has to be replaced with XBase expressions (or at least altered in a way to make them available in XBase expressions), otherwise you have to maintain two kind of expression support in your code generator or interpreter.

To conclude my answer, I believe, if you have a simple Xtext 1.0 editor, where you mostly relied on the automatically generated features, migrating to Xtext 2.0 seems easy and recommended; however, if you customized a lot of things in manually written code, be careful, because the migration might not be straight-forward, and I have found no real migration guide.

Comment: @Ujhelyi Thanks for your reply. A quick question. Did you have to change your .xtext grammer config file?

Comment: No, the grammar could remain intact (of course I did not use expressions, so no XBase migration was needed...).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/2_0_0/213-migrating-from-1.0.php#migrating_from_1_0_x_5_4

I just find this useful link.

Also I do meet some problem  especially in serialization module. Luckily in mwe2 file, it leaves a version 1.0 serialization, i use that and fix the problem when using version 2.0 serialization module. Not knowing why..

Another problem is there is a strange bug in the xtext validation. It always complain about ClassCastException. cast from String to QualifiedName error.

Answer (score 0):

It is still early considering the recent release date:
The team have just presented/demo'ed XTend2 in [democamps during last month (June 2011)](http://blog.efftinge.de/2011/06/upcoming-eclipse-democamps-featuring.html).

Comment: Thanks for update. It seems the news of xtext is mostly from Sven's blog.